# How can I convert a png to xaml DrawingBrush?

Tags: xaml, png

I have some png files that I need to use in a WPF (xaml) application in vectorial format as DrawingBrush.

How can I convert a png to xaml DrawingBrush?

Answer (score 0):

A PNG is not a vector graphic, and [making it one isn't something you can do by setting an attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343176/unable-to-create-a-scalable-png-image-using-c-sharp-in-net). You can scale it smaller, but if you try to scale it larger, you'll see some artifact. And you don't need to put it in a `DrawingBrush` to scale it either way.

The answer is to do this with an `ImageBrush`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ImageBrush
        x:Key="MyBrush"
        ImageSource="SantaClaus.png" 
        TileMode="Tile" 
        Viewport="0,0,100,100" 
        ViewportUnits="Absolute" 
        Stretch="Fill"
        />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Background="{StaticResource MyBrush}">
</Grid>
```

[image]

---

But if you're dealing with a poorly designed third party control which can only use `DrawingBrush`, you can do that too:

```
    <DrawingBrush 
        x:Key="MyBrush" 
        TileMode="Tile" 
        Viewport="0,0,100,100" 
        ViewportUnits="Absolute" 
        Stretch="Fill"
        >
        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup>
                <ImageDrawing ImageSource="SantaClaus.png" Rect="0,0,100,100" />
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    </DrawingBrush>
```